# How does the "Selected Objects, Data and Materials" option for Make Local work?

Tags: linked-data

I can not get the *"Selected Objects, Data and Materials"* option in the Make Local menu to do anything different then just the *"Selected Objects"*. I'm expecting it to make not only the object but the object data and materials local, yet it is not.
I have the same trouble with the *"Selected Objects and Data"* option.

I have tried with different linked objects, and in a saved and unsaved file, yet still the objects' data stays linked.

Here is a gif showing what I'm doing and that the object data is still linked to the source.
[image: animated gif showing the object data is still linked]

Comment: seems to work only after making the object local

Comment: O that is weird (bug territory) if you click *Selected Objects and Data* or *Selected Objects, Data and Materials* once, it only does the object. But twice works.